# CSS issue - what is causing this vertical line?

Tags: html, css

just struggling to understand where the code is that is causing a small vertical line to appear on my page: http://www.upreach.org.uk/undergraduates/benefits.php

The line appears to link the main navigation to the sub-navigation branch, annotated screenshot here: http://upreach.org.uk/old/css-vertical-line.png

I am trying to find out as I would like to implement the same line on another page, but can't get it to work: http://www.upreach.org.uk/undergraduates/is-upReach-for-me.php

Many thanks for any help that you can give...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the following element that draws that line:

```
<span class="anchor">&nbsp;</span>
```

it is in the end of the following link that is the the page the user are seeing it:

```
<a href="benefits.php" class="issue-link">
   <span>What We</span>
   Offer
   <span class="anchor">&nbsp;</span> <!-- I am here! -->
</a>
```

Element style:

```
#navigation ul li a .anchor {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    background: #333333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-indent: -4000px;
}
```

Comment: This is excellent, thank you for providing such a detailed answer so quickly!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<span class="anchor">&nbsp;</span>
```

**CSS**

```
#navigation ul li a .anchor {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -9px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -2px;
    width: 4px;
    height: 9px;
    background: #333;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    text-indent: -4000px;
}
```

It's right there. It'll need some extra HTML markup though. But you can add it with jquery if you want.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $("#navigation ul li.active a").append('<span class="anchor">&nbsp;</span>');
}
```